# At end of Not Fade Away (2012), is that Sunset Boulevard?

Tags: ending, film-location, not-fade-away

The end of writer-director David Chase's film *Not Fade Away* has the character Evelyn (Meg Guzulescu) dancing on an L.A.-area boulevard.  I assume this is Sunset Boulevard, can anyone confirm?  (It's a haunting moment, where Evelyn dances in the middle of a deserted, midnight street.)

Comment: Can you find a screenshot of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to this (youtube.com/watch?v=LBO5pLMPmDE) scene:
Yes, it shows Sunset, but not in front of the Cinerama Dome which is located at 6360 Sunset Blvd.
Meg is dancing west of Sunset and N Cahuenga.
The Dome in the movie (as CGI/build set) is located a block to the west at 6450 Sunset Blvd (Staples).
It can be easily recognized via the building right before the theater, to the left shown at 0:42 in the link above, which is 6430 Sunset Blvd (CNN).

Comment: Perhaps was easier to get permit for that next block.  In any case, thanks for the detailed confirmation!